# ORA - 00933 error in Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-intelligence

> I passed an oracle Query as an expression while creating a dataset in Report Builder.
>   I got the following error while executing the report.
>
> "ORA - 00933 : SQL command not properly ended"
>
> Below is the Oracle Query I used to create the dataset.

```
= "SELECT 
   T.TRAY_NO , 
   MAX(T.PBS) AS PBS, 
   MAX(T.SEG_CODE) AS SEG_CODE, 
   MAX(T.TYPE_CODE) AS TYPE_CODE, 
   MAX(T.WIDTH) AS WIDTH, 
   MAX(DEPTH) AS DEPTH, 
   MAX(LENGTH) AS LENGTH, 
   MAX(ALLOW_FILL) AS ALLOW_FILL, 
   MAX(TOTAL_FILL) AS TOTAL_FILL,  
   MAX(ALLOW_WEIGHT) AS ALLOW_WEIGHT, 
   MAX(TOTAL_WEIGHT) AS TOTAL_WEIGHT, 
   SUM(C.NO_OF_CABLE) AS SUM_NO_OF_CABLES, 
   MAX(IS_FILL_APPROVED) AS OVERFILL_APPROVED, 
   MAX(IS_WEIGHT_APPROVED) AS OVERWEIGHT_APPROVED, 
   MAX(FIRE_SEAL) AS FIREA_WRAPPING, 
   MAX(DESIGN_REF) AS ENOVIA_TREE_PATH, 
   MAX(LAYOUT_DWG_NO) AS WORKPACKAGE, 
   MAX(LAYOUT_DWG_REV) AS STATUS,
   CASE 
WHEN MAX(T.SEG_CODE) IN ('NL','AL','BL') THEN CEIL(SUM(TY.DIAMETER*1.4)/MAX(T.WIDTH)) 
WHEN MAX(T.SEG_CODE) IN ('NQ') THEN CEIL(SUM(TY.DIAMETER*1.1)/MAX(T.WIDTH)) 
WHEN MAX(T.SEG_CODE) IN ('NN','NS','NP','AS','BS','XR') THEN CEIL(SUM(TY.DIAMETER*1.1)/MAX(T.WIDTH)) 
ELSE CEIL(MAX(ROUTE_WIDTH)/MAX(P.WIDTH)) 
END AS NO_OF_LAYERS,

    (SELECT 
     MAX(RRW.ROOM_NO) 
     FROM EL_CMS_RACEWAY_ROOM RRW 
     WHERE RRW.RACEWAY_NO = T.TRAY_NO 
     GROUP BY RRW.RACEWAY_NO) AS ROOM_NO 

    FROM EL_CMS_TRAY T,  EL_CMS_CABLE_TYPE TY, EL_CMS_ROUTE R, EL_CMS_CABLE C,

    (SELECT 
     TRAY_NO, 
      WIDTH,
    CASE 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('HV') THEN 30 + SUM_D + 45*(N-1) + 30 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('MP') THEN 20 + SUM_D + 43*(N-1) + 20 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('MS') THEN 20 + SUM_D + 56*(N-1) + 20 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('N6','A6','B6') THEN 20 + SUM_D + 27.5*(N-1) + 20 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('AH','BH') THEN 15 + SUM_D + 12*(N-1) + 15 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('NH') AND D1=96 THEN 15 + SUM_D + 50*(N-1) + 15 
WHEN SEG_CODE IN ('NH') AND D1=126 THEN 15 + SUM_D + 12*(N-1) + 15 
END ROUTE_WIDTH 
    FROM  
    (
     SELECT 
     RACEWAY_NO R2, 
     COUNT(R.CABLE_NO) N, 
     MAX(CASE WHEN CONDUCTORS=1 THEN DIAMETER*2 ELSE DIAMETER END) D1 
     FROM EL_CMS_ROUTE R, EL_CMS_CABLE C, EL_CMS_CABLE_TYPE TYPE 
     WHERE R.CABLE_NO = C.CABLE_NO 
     AND TYPE.TYPE_CODE=C.TYPE_CODE 
     GROUP BY RACEWAY_NO
     ) , 
     (
      SELECT 
      RACEWAY_NO R1, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN CONDUCTORS=1 AND NO_OF_CABLE=3 THEN DIAMETER*2 ELSE DIAMETER END) SUM_D 
      FROM EL_CMS_ROUTE R, EL_CMS_CABLE C, EL_CMS_CABLE_TYPE TYPE 
      WHERE R.CABLE_NO = C.CABLE_NO 
      AND TYPE.TYPE_CODE=C.TYPE_CODE 
      AND SUBSTR(RACEWAY_NO,5,2) IN ('A6', 'B6', 'N6', 'HV', 'MP', 'MS', 'NH', 'AH', 'BH') 
      GROUP BY RACEWAY_NO
      ), 
      (EL_CMS_TRAY 
       WHERE R1=R2 AND TRAY_NO=R2 
       ORDER BY ROUTE_WIDTH-WIDTH DESC) P 
       WHERE C.TYPE_CODE = TY.TYPE_CODE(+) 
       AND T.TRAY_NO = R.RACEWAY_NO(+) 
       AND R.CABLE_NO = C.CABLE_NO (+) 
       AND T.TRAY_NO = P.TRAY_NO(+) 
       GROUP BY T.TRAY_NO 
       ORDER BY TRAY_NO ;
       "
```

> Can someone advice how I can resolved this error (ORA - 00933).

Comment: ORA_00933 = You tried to execute a SQL statement with an inappropriate clause. Try to run your query on the database.

Comment: I run the Query in the database and its working perfectly but only when I'm placing it as an expression in report builder it's displaying an error(ORA-00933).

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle? Inconsistent tags.

Comment: Oracle but I'm using this query as an expression in report builder.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this because I have the same problem. My query works fine in SQL Developer, but when I try to use the same query in Visual Studio / Report Builder, I get that error.

For whatever reason (maybe someone else knows why), I had to remove the semicolon (;) at the end. The error is gone and I get the results I expected.